# FFmpeg hstack, vstack and pad hangs on last frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a non-trivial layout [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q25mR.png):

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4
-filter_complex [0:v]split=3[s0][s1][s2];
                [s0][s1]hstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[s3];
                [s2]pad=width=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2[s5];
                [s3][s5]vstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[s6]
                -map [s6] -map 0:a out.mp4
```

The command is running and hangs on the last frame.

- Original video dimensions: 960x540
- When removing the `hstack` filter from the command and adjusting it, using `vstack` and `pad` it runs and finishes
- When I kill the process using `Ctrl+C` on Windows, I do get the desired output file

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report. Also share input, if possible.

Comment: @Gyan It is very simple to reproduce the issue: **1.** Build synthetic video: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=960x540:rate=5:duration=1 in.mp4`. **2.** Execute: `ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]split=3[s0][s1][s2];[s0][s1]hstack=inputs=2[s3];[s2]pad=width=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2[s5];[s3][s5]vstack=inputs=2" out.mp4`

Comment: @Rotem can't reproduce with git master; can repro with 5.0; regression appears to have been corrected between Mar 3 and 17th.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in FFmpeg (but I am not sure)...

Instead of using `split`, we may use `in.mp4` as input multiple times:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i in.mp4 -i in.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[s3];[2:v]pad=width=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2[s5];[s3][s5]vstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[s6] -map [s6] -map 0:a out.mp4`

---

Shorter command:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -an -i in.mp4 -an -i in.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[s3];[2:v]pad=width=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2[s5];[s3][s5]vstack=inputs=2 out.mp4`

---

I think the issue is related to `split=3`.
The following command (uses `split` twice) also works:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]split[s0][tmp];[tmp]split[s1][s2];[s0][s1]hstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[s3];[s2]pad=width=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2[s5];[s3][s5]vstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[s6] -map [s6] -map 0:a out.mp4`